# Setting TextView with string from string array chosen in a ListView in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, textview, arrays, settext

Alright, a quick summary. The app opens with a listView (populated by a string array), when you tap one of the items in the list it takes you to another listView (populated by a string array) with items associated with the first item you tapped. In the second listView, i'd like to tap on an item and have it display a textView with associated items from another string array. I have the first two listViews working so far, but can't get the textView to work. I've banged my head over this for two days now and am getting very frustrated. Could you please help?!

Here is my strings xml file:

```
<string-array name="topics">
<item>Idioms</item>
<item>Travel</item>
<item>Small Talk</item>
<item>Tips</item>
<item>App Data</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="idioms">
    <item>Cash Chow</item>
    <item>No Spring chicken</item> 
</string-array>

<string-array name="travel">
    <item>Asking for Change</item>
    <item>Bus and Train Schedule</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="idioms_description">
    <item>A cash cow is a blah blah blah</item>
    <item>No spring chicken means blah blah blah</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="travel_description">
    <item>This is a test for Asking for change</item>
    <item>This is a test for Bus and train schedules</item>
</string-array>
```

And here is my getIntent and place where I should setText. I left it blank because everything I have tried until now has failed miserably, I just don't know how to get the proper string from the array that was selected.

```
public class DetailLanguagePoints extends Activity{

private int position;
private TextView mLanguagePoint;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detail_view);
        mLanguagePoint = (TextView) findViewById(R.detail.languagepoints);

      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

      //int[] arrayIds = new int[]{R.array.idioms, R.array.travel};
      position = extras.getInt("listposition");

      int[] stringarrayIds = new int[]{R.array.idioms_description, R.array.travel_description};


      String[] subTopics = getResources().getStringArray(stringarrayIds[position]);

      String description = subTopics[position];

      final String TAG = "MyActivity";
      Log.d(TAG,description);

      mLanguagePoint.setText(description);      

    }

}
```

I found what the problem was with the null exception error, I didn't call `findViewById()` after `setcontentView()`.  I did that and it solved the problem, it is now working!! Thank you to all those who provided suggestions!!

Comment: did u get any error in logcat?

Comment: I changed my code a little bit, please check it above. I did two things, first, I printed the string of the selected listView item to LogCat and it printed the proper string. But it is still crashing when I click on the item in the listView. This is the error I got in LogCat E/AndroidRuntime(281): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.oiapps.everydayenglish/com.oiapps.everydayenglish.DetailLanguagePoints}: java.lang.NullPointerException
Any idea what might be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

use this code `mPosition = i.getIntExtra("listposition");`
 instead of this `mPosition = i.getIntExtra("listposition", 0);`

Comment: Eclipse gave me an error when I removed the '0'. It wants that default value.

Answer (score 0):

So you only want to set `subTopics` into a ListView?

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, subTopics);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Otherwise please post how you are failing with any logcat errors.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I actually wanted to get one string from the subTopics array and put it into a TextView. For example, if you look at the strings xml file I included above, I want to display 'Cash cow is a blah blah blah' in the text view when I click on 'Cash Cow' in the idioms array.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to display in the TextView? The two sub-items separated by a new line? If so then just change `mLanguagePoint.setText()` to `mLanguagePoint.setText(subTopics[0] + "\n" + subTopics[1])`

Comment: Actually, I wanted to show the associated string from the associated arrays. For example, if you look at the strings xml file I included, I want to display 'Cash cow is a blah blah blah' in the text view when I click on 'Cash Cow' in the idioms array.

Comment: Check down the rest of the stack trace, there may be a line saying "Caused by:" followed by another short stack trace. This could reveal the source of the exception.

Comment: Yes there is, it says, Caused by: java.lang.NullPointException   I don't know what's null though, I don't see anything in my code that could be null.

Comment: Doesn't it give the number of the line in the code that is causing the exception?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I figured out the problem, please see my edited post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

first initialize mLanguagePoint. try something like

then on second listview add `onItemClickListener()`

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg, View view, int position,long id) {


 mLanguagePoint.setText(subTopics[position]);
}
```

Comment: I fixed my original question with the edited code above, but I am still getting an error in LogCat E/AndroidRuntime(281): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.oiapps.everydayenglish/com.oiapps.everydayenglish.DetailLangua‌​gePoints}: java.lang.NullPointerException  Could this error have anything to do with not including 'mLanguagePoint.setText(subTopics[position]); in the onItemClick method in my ListView? The weird thing is that it displays the listView fine, just when I try to get to the text view that it crashes.